# How to commit files to webserver through SVN on Assembla

Tags: svn, webserver, assembla

I was recently employed with the responsibility to work on a developing website

They gave me access to Assembla, and the CPanel (They are using Hostgator)

I cloned the master repository to my computer, started modifying some files then committed the files, but I noticed that the webserver files weren't updating. Assembla was receiving the commits and was updating the files but the web-server's files remained unchanged.

Normally I would ask the head developer and not stackoverflow, however he is on vacation until Wednesday and I spoke to the project manager who doesn't have a clue. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong or what the problem could be? Is it something I am doing wrong or the configs on Assembla or something wrong with my account?

Regardless Thanks

Comment: Is web-server configured to auto-update using assembla svn ? I guess not, in which case, just upload the files manually on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the FTP tool on Assembla, if so you might want to check if you need to deploy from the FTP tool. Otherwise, you just need to upload the files to your web server - Assembla is not your host, so you need to get the files from your computer or Assembla back up to your host.